# Alternative to redis.keys(...)

Tags: python, redis

In the documentation, it strongly discourages the use of `.keys()` in a production environment. What would be an alternative to the following:

```
r = Redis()
keys = r.keys('RT*')
for key in keys:
    do_something()
```

Comment: It is not because of Python, but Redis has to pull up all the keys in it. That is why it is not recommended.

Comment: What would be a better way to iterate that then?

Comment: Group all the keys start with `RT-` in a Redis hash.

Comment: @thefourtheye ok that makes sense. Could you please show how this would be done in an Answer?

Answer (score 16):

[`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) is the recommended alternative for production usage.

[redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) includes a convenient [`SCAN` iterator](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/tree/9da5664#scan-iterators) for that purpose, so what you can do is:

```
r = Redis()
for key in r.scan_iter(match='RT*'):
  print(key) # or do something
```

Comment: match passed as a parameter to scan_iter() is optional. When passed with a valid value it allows for filtering the keys by the specified pattern.